# Give Separate Border to each element added with jquery selector

Tags: jquery, css

In trying to use the approach, of @Michael Coker my code currently looks like this:

javascript:

```
ref.child(direction + '/' + airport).once("value", function(data) {
             data.forEach(function(snapshot) {
                 $("#ride").append('<p>' + snapshot.val().from + 'to: ' + snapshot.val().to + 'day: ' + snapshot.val().when + '</p>').addClass('style');
             });
});
```

css:

```
.style{
    position: relative;
    padding: .100em;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.style p{
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5px auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    margin-left: 40%;
    border: 12px solid #888;
    border-color: #c4d8e2;
}
```

html:

While it's increased the padding between each p element, there is still no border...

---

I'm completely new to Jquery. I'm using Jquery in my javascript code to populate a div with dynamic content in my HTML page.

My javascript code looks like this:

```
function postRides(direction, airport){
        console.log("I get called");
        var ref = firebase.database().ref();
        ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
          }, function (errorObject) {
            console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
            });

         ref.child(direction + '/' + airport).once("value", function(data) {
             data.forEach(function(snapshot) {
                 $("#ride").append('<p>' + snapshot.val().from + 'to: ' + snapshot.val().to + 'day: ' + snapshot.val().when + '</p>').css('background-color', 'red');

});
}
```

I know that you can use .css to give the div with id = "ride" a background color, for example. But I'm not sure how to access/change the appearance of the content within this div. I would like for there to be a border around each string and a margin after each one. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply whatever CSS you want by targeting the `p` elements within `#ride`. What I would do instead of using `$.css()` is to add a class to `#ride` that modifies your background color, then use that same class to target the `p` elements within `#ride`.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $('#ride').append('<p>text</p>').addClass('red');
}
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
  padding: .5em;
}
.red p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: .5em;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ride"></div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your approach, but I can't get the border to show up or change the left margin

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clear about what you ask, But if you want to add border to each

element, you can simply use something like that,

```
$("#ride").append('<p style="border:1px solid #000; margin:5px">' 
   + snapshot.val().from 
   + 'to: ' 
   + snapshot.val().to 
   + 'day: ' 
   + snapshot.val().when 
   + '</p>').css('background-color', 'red');
```